# Ошибка - could not prepare statement; SQL

Tags: java, sql, spring, select

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста с чем может быть связанна следующая ошибка

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not prepare statement; SQL [select count(user0_.id) as col_0_0_ from users user0_ cross join user_roles roles1_ where user0_.id=roles1_.user_id and (upper(user0_.first_name) like ?) and (upper(user0_.first_name) like ?) and (upper(user0_.last_name) like ?) and (upper(user0_.email) like ?) and user0_.enabled=1 and .=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
```

Происходит при вызове данного метода

```
public Page<UserListingDTO> getAllUsersForListing(Pageable pageable, UserCriteria userCriteria) {
        PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize());
        Page<User> userList;
        if (userCriteria == null) {
            userList = userRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
        } else {
            SpecificationBuilder<User> builder = buildUserSpecification(userCriteria);
            userList = userRepository.findAll(builder.buildSpecification(), pageRequest);
        }
        Page<UserListingDTO> userPage = userList.map(this::convertToListingDTO);
        return userPage;
    }
```

а если конкретнее то в этой строке

```
 userList = userRepository.findAll(builder.buildSpecification(), pageRequest);
```

Comment: Что должен означать вот этот фрагмент: `and .=?`

Comment: там должен быть ещё критерий поиска (role)? который судя по всему не добавляется

Comment: Вот с это не-подстановкой и боритесь... видимо, что-то не то с массивом критериев подстановки.

Comment: В этой строчке идёт обращение к базе данных, если тесты проходят успешно, то скорее всего это связано с инфраструктурой серверов.

Comment: там всё нормально до тех пор пока в критерий поиска не добавляю тип set который  себе различные роли содержит, наверное проблема с обработкой этого сета самим sql